# ListView item not displayed correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` as the `ItemsSource` for a `ListView`.
Adding items works fine and the `ListView` updates, but in the `ListView` all I can see is this:

[image: Type name of MenuItem displayed in ListView.]

What am i missing?

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
    
// ...

public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();

// ...

MenuItemList.Add(new MenuItem {Item = MenuData[6].InnerText, Price = PriceData[6].InnerText});

// ...

listViewFood.ItemsSource = MenuItemList;
```

Comment: It seems that your ListView is missing an appropriate ItemTemplate. Or how do you expect a "correct" display?

Comment: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). As a beginner you should read the docs. You can also search the internet for tutorials. The example uses a ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a custom type `MenuItem`. The `ListView` has no way of knowing how to display items of this type, that is why it displays the result of `ToString`, which is the type name here. You have to define the appearance of an item yourself using a `DataTemplate` as `ItemTemplate`, e.g.:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewFood">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For more information see the [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which covers the mechanics in detail.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that unless you set a ListView's `View` property, you could as well use the simpler ListBox class.